# Servlet running into infinite loop when calling request.getRequestDispatcher

Tags: servlets, stack-overflow, infinite-loop

I'm trying to make a start servlet (Start.java) that is the entry point into my very simple website. Currently I have two mappings for this start servlet:

```
@WebServlet({"/Start", "/Start/*"})
```

When the user first loads the page (when invoking http://localhost:8080/MyApp/Start) a form page is loaded (Form.jspx) for them to fill out (the details of the form aren't important to the problem I'm having). What I want to do is have another jsp page (Done.jspx) load when the user loads this page: http://localhost:8080/MyApp/Start/Restore. When this page is called, I am using an unmarshaller to restore some data into my database from an XML file. The Done.jspx page simply displays how many rows were inserted from the XML file, but again I don't think this is important to my problem.

The problem I'm having is in my doGet method where I'm checking if Restore is in the URI or not. If it isn't, I load the default page which is Form.jspx. If it is in the URI, I call the request dispatcher to forward to Done.jspx. This is causing an infinite loop since when I call the dispatcher on Done.jspx it loads http://localhost:8080/MyApp/Start/Done.jspx which matches the mapping above (/Start/*) and causes the servlet to go into an infinite loop at the line where I'm loading the Form.jspx page (see below) which eventually causes a stack overflow.

The following is my doGet method

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String URI = req.getRequestURI();
    System.out.println("URI: " + URI);

    if (URI.endsWith("Restore")) {
        String filename = this.getServletContext().getRealPath("/export/backup.xml");
        model.setPath(this.getServletContext().getRealPath("/export"));
        try {
            int n = model.importXML(filename);
            req.setAttribute("numInserted", n);
            req.getRequestDispatcher("Done.jspx").forward(req, resp);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }                                                           //load default form page
    else {
        req.getRequestDispatcher("Form.jspx").forward(req, resp);
    }
}
```

I'm still very new to Java EE and servlets so it is possible that I'm going about this problem in the wrong way. I'm wondering if there is a way around this or if I'm dealing with the different URI patterns incorrectly.

Comment: try a redirect rather than a forward

Comment: I tried response.sendRedirect() for both pages but unfortunately I got the same infinite loop and stack overflow error.

Comment: What is `Done.jspx` and `Form.jspx`? Did you mean `"Done.jspx"` and `"Form.jspx"`?

Comment: Yes, sorry my apologies when copying and pasting the code i replaced the constants with the file names for clarity. I've edited it to the correct values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is about the `"/Start/*"` pattern. It will redirect/forward `/Start/Done.jspx` to the servlet, too. And this wouldn't what you are expecting.

You should make two different servlets, one for `/Start`, and the other for `/Start/Restore`

--Edited--

As your situation, you should use `@WebServlet({"/Start", "/Start/Restore"})` instead.

Comment: This was my idea as well. This is a past lab test for a class I'm preparing for and the requirement is that we don't add any additional pages or servlets. It's an annoying and restrictive requirement but I was hoping there was another way around this.

Comment: Regarding your edit, when I change the mapping to @WebServlet({"/Start", "/Start/Restore"}), when I try to redirect to the Done.jspx page I get a 404 error with the message: /MyApp/Start/Done.jspx and description: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists. Now I'm confused that I don't get an error when redirecting to the Form.jspx page but I do when redirecting to the Done.jspx page

Comment: As an update, I fixed the 404 error by changing the file names to "/Form.jspx" and "/Done.jspx". Thanks for the help!

Comment: According to the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRequestDispatcher(java.lang.String)), the `req.getRequestDispatcher()` method will use relevant path without `/`. So as `/Start/Restore`, it will look for `/Start/Done.jspx`. You can use `/Done.jspx` as absolute path, or `../Done.jspx` to forward as `Form.jspx`